# SCP Error - .+i+;I:

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

What does `.+i+;I:` mean with scp?

I'm trying to transfer a file from my laptop (OSX 10.6) to my school's linux server (RedHat 5). Ssh works normally with a public key but when I try to transfer a file with `scp file.txt school:~` the text `.+i+;I:` spits out and scp exits with code 1.

A google search shows code 1 to be a general error which isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's not an error code.

Is your remote shell "clean"?  In other words, does it spit out motd-style text even for non-interactive sessions?

Easy way to test (stolen from the rsync man page):

```
$ ssh remotehost /bin/true | wc
       0       0       0
```

If you get anything back other than a row of zeros, your shell is not clean and will not work with scp until it is made so.  As it is spewing text for non-interactive sessions, it may require admin-level intervention to fix.

EDIT:
I've verified that scp behaves exactly as I've described.  If the shell returns data in non-interactive sessions, that data is returned on the client side and scp exits with a return code of '1'.  The string you describe looks to me like terminal formatting codes.

Comment: /bin/true dumps my motd file into the ouput for some reason. Running /bin/true on an interact session returns 0 0 0.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I had a print statement in `.bashrc`... which should have been in `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a public key for ssh, you'll need to specify it for scp as well:

```
scp -i [path to your public key file] file.txt school:~
```

Comment: I have connection information stored in ~/.ssh/config which scp loads just fine. I'm able to do "scp vps:/home/user/file.ext ~" to dump a file from my VPS to my home folder.